# Entity Framework: Unable to retrieve meta data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm a newbie to Entity Framework and attempted to generate database tables from models.
Scenario:
This is a unary many to many relationship, where guest accounts can invite multiple friends who  also  owns guest accounts.
I'm given the error upon scaffolding a controller

> "Unable to retrieve meta data for Models.Friend.The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'FriendId'on type Models.Friend is not valid.The Navigation property 'GuestAccount' was not found on the dependent type Models.Friend.The Name value should be a valid navigation property name."

Here's the sample of code

```
 public class GuestAccount
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("Guest")]
    public  String UserName { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public  virtual Review Review { get; set; } 

    public virtual Guest Guest { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }


}

 public class Friend
{

    [Key,ForeignKey("GuestAccount")]
    public String FriendId { get; set; }
    public String relationship { get; set; }
    [Key,ForeignKey("GuestAccount")]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GuestAccount> GuestAccounts { get; set; }


}
```